# Python - find the ratios in a list of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, nested

I have a data structure

```
my_list = [ [a, b], [c,d], [e,f], [g,h], [i, j], [k, l] ....]
```

where the letters are floats.

I need to find the ratio between c,e and a >>>> c/a...e/a
Then find the ratio between d,f and b >>>> d/b, f/b 
and continue this for all elements 12 elements in the list.  So 8 ratios calculated.

Is there a function that can do this efficiently since we are going between list elements?  Without having to extract the data in the arrays individually first and then do the math.

Comment: Just to point it out: Don't use reserved words as variables (`list`) and list start and end with brackets `[]` not with `{}`. Dictionaries are delimited by curly braces `{}`.

Comment: @Vlad I was going to pull out the first components and second components out of each array into lists then iterate through them.  It gets long and inefficient though since I'm still having to iterate in blocks of 3 and do the calculations

Comment: @cc6g11 there are only 12 elements in the list, it's not going to take that long.

Comment: @Christian I have declared the arrays in the list as array = numpy.array([initialGAMMA, initialBETA])...causes problems with iterating them individually.

Answer (score 4):

```
ex_array = [[5.0, 2.5], [10.0, 5.0], [20.0, 13.0]]  # makes    ndarray, which makes division easier

for i in xrange(len(ex_array)):
    print "\n"  + str(ex_array[i][0]) + " ratios for x values:\n"
    for j in xrange(len(ex_array)):
        print str(ex_array[i][0] / ex_array[j][0]) + "\t|{} / {}".format(ex_array[i][0], ex_array[j][0])  # gives ratios for each nested 0 index values against the others

for i in xrange(len(ex_array)):
    print "\n"  + str(ex_array[i][1]) + " ratios for x values:\n"
    for j in xrange(len(ex_array)):
        print str(ex_array[i][1] / ex_array[j][1]) + "\t|{} / {}".format(ex_array[i][1], ex_array[j][1])   # gives ratios for each nested 1 index values against the others
```

output formatted as such:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The required operations must be specified anyway.

```
def get(l):
    return [l[i+k+1][j]/float(l[i][j]) for i in range(0, len(l)-2, 3) for j in range(2) for k in range(2)]

print get([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Using list comprehension,

```
# sample list
a = [ [1.0, 2.0], [4.0, 8.0], [3.0, 9.0] ]

print('List:', a, '\n\nMatching:')

# divides each element to other elements besides itself
xs = [ x[0] / x1[0] for x1 in a for x in a if x[0] != x1[0] ]
ys = [ y[1] / y1[1] for y1 in a for y in a if y[1] != y1[1] ]

print("Quo of x's:", xs)
print("Quo of y's:", ys)
```

Outputs to

```
List: [[1.0, 2.0], [4.0, 8.0], [3.0, 9.0]] 

Matching:
Quo of x's: [4.0, 3.0, 0.25, 0.75, 0.3333333333333333, 1.3333333333333333]
Quo of y's: [4.0, 4.5, 0.25, 1.125, 0.2222222222222222, 0.8888888888888888]
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can have some fun with [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) (builtin to stdlib since Python 2.1):

```
In [1]: from difflib import SequenceMatcher 
In [2]: SequenceMatcher(None, (5,6), (6,)).ratio()
Out[2]: 0.6666666666666666
```